# Is Changing A Generic Parameter's Name A Breaking Change

Tags: c#

When updating a library, it's important to accurately communicate any breaking changes.  Unfortunately there are a number of different kinds of breaking changes in C#, and some of them are quite subtle.

The obvious ones are things like changing the names of types or type members.

The subtle ones are things like [adding a new default parameter](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/08/10/versioning-issues-with-optional-arguments.aspx/) (binary compatibility is broken, but source compatibility is preserved), or [renaming a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018728/80572) (binary compatibility is maintained, but source compatibility is broken).

I am unsure about renaming generic parameters.

For example, is there a case where changing:

```cs
public class Foo<T>
{
  public T Bar(){ /* something */ }
}
```

to

```cs
public class Foo<TMoreDescriptive>
{
  public TMoreDescriptive Bar(){ /* something */ }
}
```

between releases of a library could break a consumer?

Comment: Take a look at the metadata in the assembly using `ILDASM`. The only information about `Foo` is that it's a Reference Type and it has a single Type Parameter (and, it there's a `where` constraint (or constraints), what that/those constraint(s) are). So, no, the name of the type parameter doesn't matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, there is no such case.

Changing the name of a generic type parameter is no more a breaking change than changing the name of a method parameter is. [According to the C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time), generic types are replaced the moment the consumer instantiates the class with a generic type argument - at no point is the consumer given the original type parameter's name except via documentation or an IntelliSense-like feature.

The guide also mentions that generic type parameters are available via reflection - this is likely the only vector by which your consumer is able to programmatically inspect the name change, similar to method parameters.

Comment: "Changing the name of a generic type parameter is no more a breaking change than changing the name of a method parameter is."
Changing the method parameter name actually **is a breaking change** for any client that is using named parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are resolved at compile time, to allow for compile time type checks. Indeed allowing those checks to still take place is what they are there for.

While I have no information either way, I do not see how this would break anything.

Source Compability is maintained.

And binary compatibility should only care what is put there instead of the T/TMoreDescriptive/type placeholder.

It is worth pointing out that .NET is **very** specific about wich .dll it loads. When .NET was made, we had at least a decade of experience that just using the dll name causes issues with versioning. So .,NET uses the DLL's name, the version and a public token (think GUID) to make certain it really is the **exact** DLL the compiler worked against. So if you want to make a major change, you can just make sure you get another public token and it should work out.

Comment: The [IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQaAMOaAzAAQDeOJVJaq5l1jAbgIYBOJwApgM7AkBeEgDsuAdxIAVXsAA8ydHgB8ACgCUAbgZUAvjj3ZCpNFJmzJABXYsAtkpwVD2HUA===) seems to instantiate the class without care for the parameter name.

Comment: The public key token isn't something that normally would change. It cryptographically represents the  identity of the assembly publisher, not the assembly. If you want to change the identity of a strongly named assembly, change the assembly version number. But, you want to be doing that with a plan to do it properly (with an understanding of backwards and forwards compatibility)

Comment: @Flydog57 My idea was about explicitly breaking compatibility without changing the name, because he wanted to make serious changes to the types. He is seriously worried about breaking code, due to it using the new version when it should the old and vice versa. I thought I point out that .NET has full support here.

Answer (score 2):

As you are just changing the name for the generic type place holder, this should not be a problem. However, as a generic rule you shouldn't make things overly complex. If your generic class only has one genetic type then T is just as clear as TSomething. In fact, the use of T has become standard for generics.
But if the generic class uses two types then more descriptive names would be better. So,

```
public class Foo<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Bar(T2 something) { return ... }
}
```

Would be bad. You would rather have

```
public class Foo<TResult, TSource>
{
    public TResult Bar(TSource something) { return ... }
}
```

But again, if there's just one type, stick to T. Changing the name won't matter as it's just a place holder.